# Can I write a script in python (or a slack app?) that allows input of one URL, that checks the succesful load of 5 different base domains?

Tags: javascript, python, url, hyperlink, slack

I work for a company that publishes articles on several different websites. I'd like to be able to enter the URL once and for it to spit out a report saying the 5 different websites show the same URL (with a different base domain for each site). Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If by "URL" you mean the part after the base domain, then use requests (something like this):

```
import requests

address = "/test/doesitexist"
bases = ["www.example.com", "www.test.com"]

for base in bases:
    i = requests.get(base + address)
    if i.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(f"{base} has {address}")
    else:
        print(f"{base} does not have {address}"
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you. I will try this out - this will be my first python learning project.